# View a list of all files changed as part of a Workitem in TFS

Tags: tfs, changeset

If I am checking in code against a workitem, on each check in a changeset is created. I can view the links tab of the workitem and then view each changeset to see the files that have been changed. Over time, however, the workitem may end up with many changesets, and finding all files that have been changed can be a very time consuming and painful process. Is there any way of finding out all files changed as part of a workitem, without viewing each changeset individually?

Comment: possible duplicate of [A way to find out all affected files of a workItem or group of chgsets in TFS 2008?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2343757/a-way-to-find-out-all-affected-files-of-a-workitem-or-group-of-chgsets-in-tfs-200)

Answer (score 2):

I needed the exact same thing and I wrote a TFS utility for myself, using TFS API. It allows you to see all changes a work item triggered over time, and some things more. I've put it on codeplex. You can get it from here:

[TFS Helper](http://tfshelper.codeplex.com)